# Processing2 2D Physics Collision at 90 degree corners

Tags: 2d, processing, physics

so this is my first post ever on asking a question about programming, so please be patient :)

For a little project in school I made a little physics class, handling collision. Although it worked out fine I still have a bug I couldn't figure out after some hours of searching and I still don't really know where the problem lies in.
For the implementation we used the on Java based language Processing which is used for an introduction to programming and prototyping.

With the a left mouseclick I can spawn some balls which collide pixel-wise with a certain color on the screen. When colliding with a 90 degree corner they just fall through the obstacle. Sadly I can't post a screenshot because of my lack in reputation.

So my question is about what the problem is. Someone I asked said it could be a problem with the dot product I use for calculating the new mirrored velocity, but I couldn't find anything in that direction. I suspect the error lies somewhere in the part where the new velocity is calculated, in the update method of the PhysicsEntity class.

So thanks to everyone who is answering, I am grateful for every useful hint :)

Here is my code, it consists of three classes. I am going to post everything so you can run the code yourself. If you don't have processing you'll need to download it from http://processing.org/ in order to run the code sample below.

**Main.pde NOTE: This part is only an example for using my physics class.**

```java
ArrayList<PhysicsEntity> entities = new ArrayList<PhysicsEntity>();

boolean mouseClicked = false;
boolean paused = false;

void setup()
{
  size(800, 600);
  background(0);
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw()
{
  if (!paused)
  {
    clear();
    float gameTime = 1 / frameRate;

    loadPixels();

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
       for (int y = height - 100; y < height; ++y)
       {
         pixels[x + y * width] = color(0, 200, 0, 128);
       } 
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
       for (int y = 0; y < 20; ++y)
       {
         pixels[x + y * width] = color(0, 200, 0, 128);
       } 
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; ++x)
    {
       for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
       {
        pixels[x + y * width] = color(0, 200, 0, 128);
       } 
    }
    for (int x = width - 100; x < width; ++x)
    {
       for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
       {
        pixels[x + y * width] = color(0, 200, 0, 128);
       } 
    }

    updatePixels();

    if (mousePressed)
    {
      entities.add(new PhysicsEntity(new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2), new Vector2(random(-100, 100), random(-100, 100)), new Vector2(0.0f, 250.0f)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); ++i)
    {
       entities.get(i).update(gameTime);
       entities.get(i).show(); 
    }
  }
}
```

**Vector2.pde NOTE: This class is just necessary for calculting things in the physics class.**

```java
class Vector2
{
   float a;
   float b;

   Vector2()
   {
     a = 0.0f;
     b = 0.0f;
   }

   Vector2(float _a, float _b)
   {
      a = _a;
      b = _b; 
   }

   /* Return exact copy of the vector */
   Vector2 Copy()
   {
     return new Vector2(a, b);
   }

   Vector2 Add(Vector2 vecB)
   {
      return new Vector2(a + vecB.a, b + vecB.b);
   }

   Vector2 Substract(Vector2 vecB)
   {
      return new Vector2(a - vecB.a, b - vecB.b);
   }

   /* Scale the vector by a scalar x */
   Vector2 Scale(float x)
   {
      return new Vector2(a * x, b * x);
   }

   Vector2 Divide(float x)
   {
      return new Vector2(a / x, b / x); 
   }

   float Dot(Vector2 vecB)
   {
       return (a * vecB.a + b * vecB.b);
   }

   float SqrLength()
   {
      return (pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)); 
   }

   float Length()
   {
       return sqrt(SqrLength());
   }

   boolean Equals(Vector2 vecB)
   {
      return (a != vecB.a || b != vecB.b) ? false : true;
   }
}

Vector2 ZeroVector()
{
   return new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f); 
}
```

**PhysicsEntity.pde NOTE: That's the class where actually failed.**

```java
class PhysicsEntity
{
  Vector2 m_Pos;
  Vector2 m_PrevPos;

  Vector2 m_Vel;
  Vector2 m_Acc;

  /* bouncyness in case of collision; gets multiplied with the velocity */
  float m_fBouncyness = 1.0f;

  color collisionKey = color(0, 200, 0, 128);

  public PhysicsEntity(Vector2 _pos, Vector2 _vel, Vector2 _acc)
  {
    if (_vel == null)
      _vel = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);

     m_Pos = new Vector2(_pos.a, _pos.b);
     m_PrevPos = m_Pos;

     m_Vel = _vel;
     m_Acc = _acc;
  }

  public void update(float dt)
  {
     /* Euler Integration more accurate Version */
     /* x = x + vt + 0.5*at^2 */
     m_Pos = m_Pos.Add(m_Vel.Scale(dt)).Add(m_Acc.Scale(pow(dt, 2)).Scale(0.5));
     /* v = v + at */
     m_Vel = m_Vel.Add(m_Acc.Scale(dt));

     /* Collision based on color key */
     if (isCollidable(m_Pos.a, m_Pos.b, collisionKey))
     {
        float speed = m_Vel.Length();
        if (speed > 0.0f)
        {
          /* normalized vector of velocity */
          Vector2 velNorm = m_Vel.Divide(speed);
          /* getting the floor normal */
          Vector2 floorNorm = interp(m_Pos, m_PrevPos);

          if (!floorNorm.Equals(ZeroVector()))
          {
            /* mirror velocity on floor normal vector */
            /* C = A - (2 * B * (A dot B)) where A is original vector, B the mirror, C result. */
            Vector2 mirVel = velNorm.Substract(floorNorm.Scale(2.0f).Scale(velNorm.Dot(floorNorm)));

            /* caculate new velocity */
            m_Vel = mirVel.Scale(speed).Scale(m_fBouncyness);
            /* add to position to move out of collision */
            m_Pos = m_Pos.Add(m_Vel.Scale(dt));
          }
        }
     }

     m_PrevPos = m_Pos;
  }

  public void show()
  {
    ellipse(m_Pos.a, m_Pos.b, 10, 10);
  }

  public Vector2 interp(Vector2 pos, Vector2 PrevPos)
  {
    /* Vector from previous position to current position */
    Vector2 line = pos.Substract(PrevPos);

    float iLength = line.Length();
    Vector2 lineFraction = ZeroVector();
    /* checks if there the is vectorlength greater zero that connects the current and the previous position */
    if (iLength > 0.0f)
      lineFraction = line.Divide(iLength);

    /* loop from through positions between previous position and current position */
    for (int i = 0; i <= iLength; ++i)
    {
       Vector2 normVec = getNormal(PrevPos.Add(lineFraction.Scale(i)), collisionKey);

       if (!normVec.Equals(ZeroVector()))
         return normVec;
    }

    return ZeroVector();
  }
}

/* returns normal vector of a 2d landscape in a certain area */
public Vector2 getNormal(Vector2 pos, color col)
{
  int area = 10;

  /* prevent coordinates from being out of the window */
  if (pos.a <= area || pos.a >= width - area || pos.b <= area || pos.b >= height - area)
   return ZeroVector();

  Vector2 avg = new Vector2();
  float loops = 0;

  /* loop through an area of pixels */
  for (int x = -area; x <= area; ++x)
  {
     for (int y = -area; y <= area; ++y)
     {
        if (x*x + y*y <= area*area)
        {
          float sumX = pos.a + float(x);
          float sumY = pos.b + float(y);
          /* count collidable pixels in area */
          if (isCollidable(sumX, sumY, col))
          {
             /* add up positions of these pixels */
             avg.a += sumX;
             avg.b += sumY;
             ++loops;
          }
        }
     }
  }

  if (loops == 0)
    return ZeroVector();

  /* calculate average position */
  avg = avg.Divide(loops);
  /* calculate length of the vector from initial position to average position */
  float avgLength = dist(avg.a, avg.b, pos.a, pos.b);

  /* check if avgLenth is zero or in other words: if avg is equals to pos */
  if (avgLength == 0.0f)
    return ZeroVector();

  /* calculate vector(connection vector) from initial position to average position */
  Vector2 conVec = pos.Substract(avg);
  /* return normalized connection vector */
  return conVec.Divide(avgLength);
}

/* method to check if pixel on a certain position is collidable */
public boolean isCollidable(float pixelX, float pixelY, color col)
{
  if (pixelX >= width || pixelX < 0 || pixelY >= height || pixelY < 0)
    return false;

  return pixels[int(pixelX) + int(pixelY) * width] == col;
}
```

**Edit1:**
So thanks to the friendly first replay I stripped my code by a few lines :) If there is still a problem with my post let me know!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. That's a *lot* of code for what should be a very simple task. I strongly recommend that you learn to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org), the shortest and simplest code that will reproduce the problem. It's a valuable skill that will make you a better programmer, and it makes our job of helping you much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I cant analyze correctness of your whole physic calculation but in my opinion problem is with calculation of new velocity and :

```
/* caculate new velocity */
m_Vel = mirVel.Scale(speed).Scale(m_fBouncyness);   
/* add to position to move out of collision */
m_Pos = m_Pos.Add(m_Vel.Scale(dt));
```

Because if you change `m_fBouncyness` to real value simulating some gravitation (`0.8f` or less) your problem will never occur but if you change it to some unreal value like `2.0f` you will lose all your balls after few bounces.

This indicate problem in algorithm. Your approach consist (in simple) of this steps in loop:

- update position of ball

  - calculate new position
  - correct position depending on bounce
- draw ball

Here can be problem because you calculate new position of ball - this position is out of black box so you calculate average position then new velocity and correct new position. Then draw ball and repeat but what if this new position is also out of the black box? This ball will bounce out of border ... this happens in corner because of calculation of average position (in corner you got far away from black box then at classic border (when you set `m_fBouncyness` to some bigger value this will happen even on normal border not only in corner!))

Hope this could help you to find your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply :) That's the kind of answer I was looking for. If I have found the solution I am going to post it :)

Answer (score 0):

So finally I've got a solution.

It appears that the answer of Majlik was very helpful. According to his answer I did a few changes which I will explain now.

First of all I put the if-statement if (speed > 0.0f) way up, over the whole movement code so nothing happens anymore if the speed is too low. Of course you can define a certain treshold which works for you.

In addition to that I introduced an else-case, for the if(colliding) statement, in which the movement code is handled, so if the ball is currently colliding it doesn't move at all apart from the collision handling code.

Finally I thought of a new way to move the ball out of the collision. The suggestion of Maljik proved to be right. My previous method didn't move the ball out of the collision at all.
For that I made a while loop which loops as long as the ball is still in collision. In every runthrough the ball gets moved by a normalized vector with the same direction as my mirrored velocity vector. For safety reasons I still got an iterator incrementing every time, so it doesn't end in an infinite loop.

After all the solution was very obvious. But thanks to those who answered.

Below the new changed code:

```java
  public void update(float dt)
  {
     float speed = m_Vel.Length();
     if (speed > 0.0f)
     {       
       /* Collision based on color key */
       if (isCollidable(m_Pos.a, m_Pos.b, collisionKey))
       {
          /* normalized vector of velocity */
          Vector2 velNorm = m_Vel.Divide(speed);
          /* getting the floor normal */
          Vector2 floorNorm = interp(m_Pos, m_PrevPos);

          if (!floorNorm.Equals(ZeroVector()))
          {
            /* mirror velocity on floor normal vector */
            /* C = A - (2 * B * (A dot B)) where A is original vector, B the mirror, C result. */
            Vector2 mirVel = velNorm.Substract(floorNorm.Scale(2.0f).Scale(velNorm.Dot(floorNorm)));

            /* caculate new velocity */
            m_Vel = mirVel.Scale(speed).Scale(m_fBouncyness);

            int it = 0;
            Vector2 normMirVel = mirVel.Divide(mirVel.Length());
            while (isCollidable(m_Pos.a, m_Pos.b, collisionKey) && it < 100)
            {
              /* add to position to move out of collision */
              m_Pos = m_Pos.Add(normMirVel);
              ++it;
            }
          }
       }
       else
       {
         /* Euler Integration more accurate Version */
         /* x = x + vt + 0.5*at^2 */
         m_Pos = m_Pos.Add(m_Vel.Scale(dt)).Add(m_Acc.Scale(pow(dt, 2)).Scale(0.5));
         /* v = v + at */
         m_Vel = m_Vel.Add(m_Acc.Scale(dt)); 
       }
     }

     m_PrevPos = m_Pos;
  }
```

Edit: I might that this is not an ideal soluation since the ball gets moved further than it should in this frame. Maybe you should only calculate the necessary distance to move out of collision and add the actual velocity step by step. Also you could compare the current velocity direction to the direction where it should go. If it's already moving in the right direction there is no interference needed.